# Find five consecutive odd integers such that their sum is $55$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, contest-math

So my professor asked us to do an Olympiad exercise which says that the sum of five consecutive odd integers is $55$, find those integers. But I've never seen such an exercise so it is quite new and if I learn how then I will be able to solve similar exercises.

I tried to think of it in terms of geometry but that didn't help me.

Comment: let the first be n, then what are the others?

Comment: It's simpler to let the third number be n.

Comment: Just curious - what specifically did you try with geometry? There are reasonable ways to use geometry here.

Comment: $1$kviews, $10$ votes and $10$ answers with a lot of votes! I can't think how did this question go this far...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

let k be the smallest number. Then you have $k+(k+2)+(k+4)+(k+6)+(k+8)=55.$ So you get $5k+20=55\rightarrow 5k=35\rightarrow k=7$

Comment: Perhaps a better choice of notation would've been $k\pm1$, $k\pm3$, and $k+5$.

Comment: But then k would not be the least element. Other answers use k as the third least element (aka the average) this one uses k as the smallest.

Answer (score 79):

Avoiding explicit algebra computation, their average would be $11$ and they would have to surround that average symmetrically.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, the "right" way to solve the problem. But if someone doesn't immediately think of it, then I think the next best approach (better than setting up algebraic equations) is trial and error.

Comment: Why do you think that? How would you justify trial and error over an algebraic approach?

Comment: Neat - my first gold badge.

Comment: Cool, glad my noobness could help you. :)

Comment: mark of a true genius!

Comment: Short and sweet. I love this answer!

Comment: @user4140 If someone doesn't immediately think of alex.jordan's solution, then the work needed to think of and carry out an algebraic solution would be considerably more than the work needed for trial and error. Here I'm taking into account both that such a person is unlikely to react to the question as a mathematician would (and thus unlikely to come up with the algebraic idea) and that the solution is quite small and easily found after a few trials and errors.

Comment: I agree with the fact this solution is neat. But I do not think the fact the answer is small makes up for the fact it is time consuming and a lot less useful for larger cases. Also the fact a non-mathematician might not come up with it is not bad. Finally: if the number of numbers was even then we would have to modify this approach a little, so it also takes some time to figure this out. While the algebraic approach can be set up immediately, while it is true it does take away time later due to the calculations.

Comment: @user4140 Aside from changing the number from $11$ to something else, I would use the exact same wording if it were an even number of numbers, an odd number of even numbers, etc.

Comment: @user4140 This key idea in this proof does in fact generalize quite widely. It is a simple, prototypical example of the exploitation of innate symmetry (here a reflection or involution). For many further nontrivial examples see the links in comments to my answer.

Comment: I always have used this method and I thought very few people used to approach such problems this way! When the no. of nos. is odd, simply divide sum by $n$, and assign that value to the central no., or in this case, 3. If no. of nos is even, then again divide sum by $n$ and add and subtract 1. That gives central nos. The other nos. lie symmetrically as you said. :)

Answer (score 15):

**Hint:** Choose one of those equations and solve it:
$$\begin{align}
& \text{The first integer:} & \qquad x+\color{blue}{x+2+x+4+x+6+x+8}=55 \\\,\\
& \text{The second integer:} & \qquad \color{red}{x-2}+x+\color{blue}{x+2+x+4+x+6}=55 \\\,\\
& \text{The third integer:} & \qquad \color{red}{x-4+x-2}+x+\color{blue}{x+2+x+4}=55 \\\,\\
& \text{The fourth integer:} & \qquad \color{red}{x-6+x-4+x-2}+x+\color{blue}{x+2}=55 \\\,\\
& \text{The fifth integer:} & \qquad \color{red}{x-8+x-6+x-4+x-2}+x=55
\end{align}$$
Obviously the simplest choice is to solve for the third integer, since the $2$s and $4$s cancel out, and you're left with the simple equation, $5x=55$.

Answer (score 12):

**Hint** $\, $ The sum of an odd number $k$ of terms in arithmetic progression is $k$ times the middle term, since the differences $\,\color{#c00}{\pm\Delta}\,$ from the middle term $\,n\,$ cancel out on addition, e.g. for $\,k=7$

$$\begin{eqnarray} n &\,+\,& n\!\color{#c00}{+\!a} &\,+\,& n\!\color{#c00}{+\!2a} &\,+\,& n\!\color{#c00}{+\!3a} \\
&\,+\,& n\!\color{#c00}{-\!a} &\,+\,& n\!\color{#c00}{-\!2a} &\,+\,& n\!\color{#c00}{-\!3a} \\
\hline
=\ 7n \end{eqnarray}$$

Thus, in your case we have $\ 5n = 55\ \Rightarrow\ n =\,\ldots$

Comment: How could one downvote such excellent answer?

Comment: @Adobe Perhaps they thought I should have said it with words instead of algebra - as in Alex's later answer. I was tempted to do that, but I think the algebra makes more precise the key idea (innate reflection *symmetry*). This is but one of many beautiful proofs that work by *pairing* elements using *reflections* or *involutions,* e.g. see [Wilson's theorem for groups.](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+wilson+theorem+group) Also, be aware that this question was on the SE Hot List, so it got many visitors from other sites. So votes may not be representative of MSE.

Comment: @Adobe See also the legendary example: [Gauss's grade school method](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/7077/242) of quickly summing the first $\,100\,$ integers.

Comment: @Adobe - by accident. On my iPad, meant to upvote, dog jumped on me, couldn't undo. My vote is locked until Bill edits the answer. I was in my usual money.SE just now and saw my history showed a Math DV. Just realized what happened. Sorry, all.

Answer (score 6):

We have

$$\sum_{k=p}^{p+4} (2k+1)=55\iff2\times\frac{5(p+4+p)}{2}+5=55\iff p=3$$
so the first odd number is $7$.

Comment: A variant is to use the formula for the sum of an arithmetic series, $ \ s \ = \ \frac{n}{2} \ \cdot \ [2a_1 \ + \ (n - 1) \cdot d] \ $ , with  $ \ a_1 \ $ being the initial term, $ \ d \ $ being the difference between terms , and $ \ n \ $ being the number of terms.  For this question, we need to solve  $ \ \frac{5}{2}  \ \cdot \ [2a_1 \ + \ (5 - 1) \cdot 2] \ = \ 55 \ $ for $ \ a_1 \ $ .

Comment: ${}{}{}{}{}{}+1$

Comment: $\widetilde{\color{red}{\boxed{+1}}}$

Comment: ${}{}{}$Thanks @Adobe

Answer (score 5):

As consecutive  odd numbers differ by $2$

and we have **odd** number of integer terms (namely $5$), its beneficial take the numbers to be $n,n\pm2,n\pm4$

Had the number of odd integers been **even**, we could take $n\pm1,n\pm3,\cdots$

Answer (score 4):

I did it this way:

We need 5 consecutive odd numbers who add up to 55, so their mid/centre or the 3rd (arithmetic mean) number must be 55/5 which is 11(as the sequence is symmetric about this number). The previous two and the next two odd numbers complete the needed sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the numbers as $x-4,x-2,x,x+2,x+4$. Now, our equality takes the form

$$(x-4) + (x-2) + x + (x+2) + (x+4) = 55,$$

so $5x = 55$, i.e., $x = 11$.

We conclude that the numbers are $7,9,11,13,15$.

Answer (score 2):

For odd numbers the answer is :$(x-4)+ (x-2)+x+(x+2)+(x+4)=55$ i.e. $5x= 55$ therefore $x=11$, and the series would be: $7+9+11+13+15=55$.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of five consecutive odd integers is $55$.

Let $n$ = any integer.

Then $2n$ = an even integer

and  $2n + 1$ = an odd integer.

Thus $\color{red}{\underbrace{2n +1}},\underbrace{(2n+1)+\color{blue}{2}},\underbrace{ (2n+1)+\color{blue}{4}},\underbrace{(2n+1)+\color{blue}{6}},\underbrace{(2n+1)+\color{blue}8} $

are five consecutive odd integers. The sum is $$10n + 25 =55$$ $$10n=30$$$$n=3$$ This gives $\color{red}{\overbrace{2(3)+1}}=7$ as the $\color{red}{first}$ of the five consecutive odd integers whose sum is $55$.